# What is the purpose of Fields class in Apache Storm

Tags: apache-storm

I was going through one of the example of Apache Storm. 
Following is the snippet of the Bolt class 
    public void declareOutputFields(OutputFieldsDeclarer declarer) { 
    declarer.declare(new Fields("word"));
}

Declarer is used to denote the kind of field that Bolt will emit. so what does above syntax mean when it says " new Fields("word") ".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It defines the schema of your output tuples. Ie, how many attributes a tuple has and a name for each attribute.

`Fields("word")` defines a schema with a single attribute named `word`. Thus, if you call `collector.emit(new Values(...))`, the parameter list must contain a single value.

On the receiver side (ie, the bolt that consumes the output stream) you can access the attributes via index or name; the name is the one that is declared via `Fields` by the producer.

In your example the consumer can access the attribute via `input.getX(0)` or `input.getXByName("word")`.

Comment: So what you are saying is that - here "word" doesn't have any significance. we can use any string instead of word and it should work. The only thing i need to take care is that string "word" should be same in Fields("word") and new Values("word"). Am i correct ?

Comment: Yes, almost. You can give any name for attributes. While "word" is the name of the attribute, `new Values("actualWord")` creates a new Tuple with attribute value "actualWord" for the attribute "word". If you access attributes via index in the receiver bolt the name of the attribute has no importance.